# Unity - character starts to fly up when there should be gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a **2D platform game**, where the character is a ball and **should be able to move right and left, and to jump**. It now does all that, but for some reason which i do not understand (as i am **complitely new to Unity**) sometimes **it flies up like if the gravity was negative**.

Here is the code of my first script ***Move2D***:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public bool isGrounded = false;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    private Vector2 currentMoveDirection;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        currentMoveDirection = Vector2.zero;
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidbody.velocity = (currentMoveDirection + new Vector2(0f, rigidbody.velocity.y)).normalized * moveSpeed;

    }

    public void TriggerMoveLeft()
    {
        currentMoveDirection += Vector2.left;
    }

    public void StopMoveLeft()
    {
        currentMoveDirection -= Vector2.left;
    }

    public void TriggerMoveRight()
    {
        currentMoveDirection += Vector2.right;
    }

    public void StopMoveRight()
    {
        currentMoveDirection -= Vector2.right;
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the second script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ContinuesButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Button targetButton;

    [SerializeField] private Move2D playerMovement;

    [SerializeField] private bool movesLeft;

    private readonly bool isHover;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!targetButton) targetButton = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (movesLeft)
        {
            playerMovement.TriggerMoveLeft();
        } else
        {
            playerMovement.TriggerMoveRight();
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (movesLeft)
        {
            playerMovement.StopMoveLeft();
        } else
        {
            playerMovement.StopMoveRight();
        }
    }
}
```

> I noticed that the ball starts to fly up as soon as the movement controller or some collider makes it go up a bit. For example when i make it jump, it just keeps going up, or when in the game i try to make it "walk" up a hill, it immediately starts flying up.

**Any help or information is really appreciated**, I really do not see the problem.

Comment: I think your problem come from your FixedUpdate method: `rigidbody.velocity = (currentMoveDirection + new Vector2(0f, rigidbody.velocity.y)).normalized * moveSpeed;`

Comment: You add an `y` velocity each frame that is the same as the previous frame.

Comment: @EnricoCortinovis .. probably by not adding it every frame? In short you are doubling the Y-velocity everytime .. not sure what your goal is with that

Comment: @derHugo I wanted to make so that the ball would continiously move when the right and left buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I lies in `normalized`. This might unexpectedly increase the Y velocity. Especially in cases when you set the X velocity to `0` the Y component is taken into account to much.

I guess you should rather use something like

```
currentDirection * moveSpeed + Vector2.up * rigidbody.velocity.y;
```

In order to simply keep the current Y velocity.

---

Also be careful with these `currentDirection += ...`! I would suggest rather use single methods and use fixed values like e.g.

```
public void DoMove(bool right)
{
    currentDirection = (right ? 1 : -1) * Vector2.right;
}

public void StopMove()
{
    currentDirection = Vector2.zero;
}
```

And then rather call them like

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    playerMovement.DoMove(!movesLeft);
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    playerMovement.StopMove();
}
```